How do I get the keyedAppStates from the application report for AMAPI?
I'm attempting to access the keyedAppStates in order to retrieve app feedback from the Reports application. I have followed the instructions in this link.
https://developers.google.com/android/management/app-feedback
https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications
Here's the code I've tested for enterprise requests.:-
    const EnterPriseRequest = {
      name: enterpriseName,
      resource: {
      enabledNotificationTypes: ["STATUS_REPORT"], // Valid types
      pubsubTopic:`projects/${project_id}/topics/MyTopic`,
        contactInfo,
      },
      updateMask: 'enabledNotificationTypes,contactInfo',
    };
androidManagementClient.enterprises.patch(enterPriseRequest)

Getting Device Infromation:-
androidManagementClient.enterprises.devices.get({
      name: deviceId,
    });

I've followed all the instructions and I'm now receiving the application events,
 "events": [
    {
      object (ApplicationEvent)
    }
  ],

but there is no data coming through in keyedAppStates. Can someone provide a solution to this issue?

You may want to check if the app is integrated with the Enterprise Jetpack library (such as Gmail) as this is one of the requirements for an app to send out feedback.
You will also need to update the device policy to enable applicationReportsEnabled:
"statusReportingSettings": {
"applicationReportsEnabled": true }

